# Display report in detail page

Tags: visualforce, reporting

I want to display a table that looks like a matrix report that I've built on an Opportunity detail page. I know I can display the report chart, however, I want to see the columns and values for each row so I need the data.

Is there a way to display the results for a report inside a vf page to drop on the page through the reporting api or do I need to create a table from scratch and then dynamically build out the columns and totals.

Either way, I've been looking for examples and how-tos and am not finding a lot of results so it makes me think I'm going about this in the wrong way.

Comment: Why are you taking so much pain which can be easily provided by a link to report?

Comment: Sales Bros were all let's see it on the page so they don't have to click. :(